# Do I need Google Apps for Business to send email to more than 100 recipients?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have groups of more than 100 and keep having to split them in order to send. I don't really understand apps for business because there is too much information. All I want to do is keep my current structure which is that I have 3 google accounts which come through on to my apple computer. Can i apply for a higher limit or do i need to go to business apps? Does this cost? Will I have to make changes to my current setup? Also, isn't an app just for phones?

Richard Woods

Answer (score 1):

The max 100 recipients limit is probably implemented to prevent you from sending spam.

If you regularly send email to groups, you should consider creating a Google Group. This gives the recipients the possibility to unsubscribe from your group, if they no longer want to receive your emails.

To set up your group, go to https://groups.google.com, click *Create group*, and fill in the following form. This includes specifying a *group email address*, that will be the one *you* send your emails to.

Google then lets you invite members to join your group. This will cause your recipients to receive an invitation, that they must respond to in order to receive your messages.

If you already know that they would like that, you can click *Add members* instead. Make sure you select *All email*, so that your members receive every single email you send.